# Inconsistant Variation in BLE Beacon RSSI Values for Distance Measurement

Tags: filters, signal-detection, kalman-filters, median-filter

I am developing an application to estimate the distance to a BLE Beacon using its RSSi values measured from a Mobile Phone. But when I started to collect data I could see that they varied so much that I cannot possibly estimate the distance using the values. Even though I implemented mean and median filters with various window sizes, the RSSI values are highly varying. Is this a common problem with RSSI values ? Is there a way to eliminate/filter out these variations so that I can input them to a distance modal ? Help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: RSSI is not a good, reliable indicator. Search for 'rssi' on this website and you'll find a few questions related to this.